# how to redirect traceback.print_exc to logging

Tags: python, debugging, logging, exception, eventlet

I am using `eventlet` with Python to spawn some threads. I am using `eventlet.spawn_n()`. I can see from the implementation here that it prints a stack trace if the method you run throws an exception: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/79292bd16a6a1384d8c3d11bcefa40eb53bbeae4/eventlet/greenpool.py#L93

This stack trace is going to stderr. But the logging for everything else in my program goes to a file using `WatchedFileHandler`. This causes the stack traces to not be shown in the the log file where the rest of the logging for my application takes place which is causing some problems.

**Is there a way to get the stack traces from eventlet to print to the same file that the rest of my application logs to rather than printing to stderr?**

Here is the logging configuration I currently use:

```
[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = watchedfile

[formatters]
keys = default

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = watchedfile

[handler_watchedfile]
class = handlers.WatchedFileHandler
args = ('my_log.txt',)
formatter = default

[formatter_default]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s] %(pathname)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s %(message)s
```

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is what you observe happens with `eventlet.greenpool.DEBUG` enabled (by default). And it prints traceback of **uncaught exceptions**. Things you should've wrapped in try/except. Without that safeguard debug print_exc, you'd have errors that are just lost. Forgetting about errors is bad.

As you pointed in code, it uses `traceback.print_exc()`, so question could be rewritten w/o Eventlet to "how to redirect traceback.print_exc to logging". Or even "how to redirect sys.stderr to logging". You may find better solutions with that.

Redirects aside, your options:

- just use `GreenPool.spawn()`, it reraises exceptions in thread that gets results (usually in form of `pool.waitall()`)
- use stderr handler, write to file using external program, such as syslog, it solves more issues than just reopening rotated logs
- catch errors in spawned function and use logging

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So is there nothing that I can just add to my existing log configuration to make this work?

Comment: You can write a custom logging handler that does stderr redirect and mention it in logging configuration.

Comment: I've expanded answer, hopefully to get point across that your problem is not related to logging per se.